# addEventListener for mouseover works within a function but not outside the function

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, mouseover

I am making an etch-a-sketch and I am trying to use an addEventListener event of 'mouseover' to add a CSS class where the background of the square the mouse hovers over will turn black.  I have a function that creates a single box and if I put the event listener inside this function it works, however if I try to do it outside the function it doesn't work

The function box creates a single box (which will get repeated using the addMultipleBox function) and adds a mouseover event.  In this scenario the mouseover works correctly

```
function box() {
    let square = document.createElement('div')
    square.setAttribute('class', 'box')
    container.appendChild(square)

    square.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        square.classList.add('blackPen')
    })
}

//creates the etch a sketch board with multiple 'boxes'
function addMultipleBoxes() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        box()
    }
}
```

Now if I try and grab the class of 'box' outside the function and add an event listener to it nothing happens.  I do have this code at the bottom so it's not like i'm trying to grab divs before they are created.

I'd like to be able to grab it outside so I can create another function that on a mouse click I remove the class of 'blackPen' which will remove the background color of black on the square, essentially wiping the board clean.  Here is what I have for that

```
let boxx = document.querySelector('.box')

console.log(boxx)

boxx.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    boxx.classList.add('blackPen')
})
```

When I console.log 'Boxx' I get the `<div class="box"></div>`.  If I console.log "square" above in the box function I get the same thing as Boxx.

Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: "I do have this code at the bottom so it's not like i'm trying to grab divs before they are created." - but have you created the divs by calling the function? They have to exist in the document tree before you can attach an event listener to them.

Comment: I call the boxes function inside the addMultipleBoxes function and I call that function on page load

Comment: Your code appears to be fine. I think the answer provided by @DavePritlove will fix this for you. If you are only selecting a single box, then the hover effect will only work on that one box - the first one found by the querySelector command. Use querySelectorAll to grab all the boxes. You can store this collection and perform multiple transformations on all the boxes at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `box()` function adds the class to each element as it is made, as required.

A reference made to an element using `querySelector` contains only one element - the first in the document with the specified selector. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

This snippet illustrates the idea with four divs, all the same class.

```js
let boxx = document.querySelector('.box')


boxx.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    boxx.classList.add('blackPen')
})
```

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.blackPen {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<p><b>mouseover applied to element got by querySelector</b></p>
<p>(move mouse over divs)</d>

<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>

<p>querySelector, returns the <em>first</em> Element within the document that matches the specified selector</p>
```

A reference to all elements with a given class can  be made using `querySelectorAll()`,  which returns a live node list with references to all the elements of the given selector. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Having made the reference, you will still have to loop through them in order to add the event listeners required. node lists and html collections are *array-like* structures that can have individual members referenced by and index `[0]`,`[1]`, and so on.

This snippet illustrates adding a new class to each div in a node list formed using querySelectorAll:

```js
let boxx = document.querySelectorAll('.box')



for (let i=0; i<boxx.length; i++) {

boxx[i].addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    boxx[i].classList.add('blackPen');
    boxx[i].classList.remove('cancel');
});

boxx[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    boxx[i].classList.add('cancel')
});

} // next i boxx element;
```

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.blackPen {
  background: black;
}

.cancel {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p><b>mouseover applied to all elements got by querySelectorAll</b><br>(move mouse over divs)</d>

<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>

<p>A click event was also added to all elements, to replace the class added by the mouseover event<br>click boxes to see the effect</p>
```

Note that the node collection only needs to be made once to be used for any further manipulations. In the snippet a mouseover event adds a class to make the background black while a click event cancels it.

Comment: This was super helpful!  I actually went and used a `forEach()` loop and it worked just as good.  Didn't consider querySelectorAll so good catch